# Python script calling a C function, which calls a Python function

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm a regular C user, but pretty new to Python.

I have a library written in C for performing calculations that I'm trying to make callable from a Python script. The library needs some user defined routines, for which I am trying to allow the use of Python scripts.

I am running into a problem which demonstrates to me that I do not understand something very fundamental. Here is the code for a simple program I cannot get to run. It should print to the screen the result of 7 (2+5).

The Python script test.py is called first. It loads ctypes and the library libfoo.so, and calls the C routine `c_do_work`:

```python
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

print "Python 1: Going in..."
lib.c_do_work(2,5)
```

The C function `c_do_work` is defined in the library libfoo.so, which has the single module test.c. This routine should run the Python script my_func.py, which defines the function `find_sum`. A Python interpreter is initialized here:

```c
//gcc test.c -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -L/usr/lib/python2.7/ -lpython2.7 -lm -fPIC -c
//gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so  test.o
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void c_do_work(int a,int b)
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    PyObject* main_dict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module);

    FILE* file_1 = fopen("my_func.py", "r");
    PyRun_File(file_1, "my_func.py",Py_file_input,main_dict, main_dict);
    PyObject* expression = PyDict_GetItemString(main_dict,"find_sum");

    printf("C: calling Python function...\n");
    PyObject_CallFunction(expression,"ii",a,b);

    //Clean up
    fclose(file_1);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

Lastly, the Python script my_func.py:

```python
def find_sum(a, b):
    print a+b
```

When I run "python test.py", I get a segmentation fault at the second line of the C function:

```c
PyObject* main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
```

Why is this happening? If I slightly rewrite the C routine so it is main, and run that program directly, I get the desired result. The problem seems to be related to having a Python interpreter calling a routine that initializes a Python interpreter.

Comment: For a slightly different approach, have you considered using Cython?  http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

Comment: The script for `lib.c_do_work(2,5)` has already loaded an initialized the interpreter for the current process. Don't call `Py_Initialize` or `Py_Finalize`. Also, you need to hold the GIL (global interpreter lock), so use `lib = ctypes.PyDLL('./libfoo.so')`.

Comment: The GIL can be released for functions that don't use the interpreter. For that you can load a separate copy as `lib_nogil = ctypes.CDLL('./libfoo.so')`.

Comment: Instead of using `CDLL` it is much cleaner to create a "real" python extension. You can then do the normal `import foo; print foo.find_sum(3,4)`. The idea of CDLL is to provide an interface to existing DLL's. But if you are writing a library on your own, you are much better off using python's native facilities. See the documentation for "Extending Python with C or C++" and "The C/API Reference Manual".

Comment: If you're set on starting a new interpreter, try replacing `Py_Initialize` with `PyThreadState *old_tstate = PyThreadState_Swap(NULL);` `PyThreadState *new_tstate = Py_NewInterpreter();`. And in place of `Py_Finalize` use `Py_EndInterpreter(new_tstate);` `PyThreadState_Swap(old_tstate);` The GIL needs to be held, so use `PyDLL`.

Comment: @DovGrobgeld, I wouldn't recommend the C API. It's error prone to handle manual reference counting and resource management. I need to stress that my own comments are just showing how to do what the OP wants in principle. The suggestion from Ryan to use Cython is much nicer than mucking about with these low-level interfaces.

Comment: @eryksun, it all boils down to how much power you want and with power comes responsibility. I admit I haven't used cython, but I have written several extensions directly in C. Keeping count of the reference counts is really not worse than remembering to do free/delete in C/C++. Of course in C++ you can use smart pointers and some people consider C to be too low-level. The choice is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. First, I was under the impression I needed to start a new interpreter, but that is apparently not the case. I will have to read more about the GIL, but switching to PyDLL does the trick.

I have been reading about the C API and Cython. Thanks for those links. Adding wrappers to create a module for the libraries makes a lot more sense for me than using cdll or pydll. I will probably go this route ultimately.